# how to setup nginx config to make from react js to communicate with node js in docker

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, nginx

I am trying to dockerize my personal application. Usually in local we mention the server(http://server:4000) in the package.json file of react. But in production when we build the react app , we don't use pacakge.json. We have to config the nginx server to redirect the api calls to my node js server.

Here is my nginx config and my containers.

**Containers:**
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS
NAMES
10b8d0bf6b2e   abc/client:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   43 minutes ago   Up 27 minutes   0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp, :::8001->80/tcp
client
ed73637b394d   abc/api:latest      "node index.js"          5 days ago       Up 39 minutes   0.0.0.0:4000->4000/tcp, :::4000->4000/tcp
node
6ead7807604a   mongo                       "docker-entrypoint.s…"   6 days ago       Up 42 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp, :::27017->27017/tcp
db

Comment: **Nginx config:**

upstream api {
    server node: 4000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen[::]: 80;

    location / {
        root /
        var / www / html;
        index index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri / index.html;
        proxy_pass http: //api;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }

    error_page 404 / 404. html;
    error_page 403 / 403. html;

    # To allow POST on static pages
    error_page 405 = 200 $uri;

}

Answer (score 0):

For prod I use this for `Dockerfile` and keep build generated from React project behind Nginx

```
FROM node:12-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY ./nginx/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

`/nginx/default.conf` file, `nginx` dir. should be at same level of `package.json`

```
server {
  listen 80;

  location / {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
  }
}
```